# JS a way to know if attribute value is double quoted, single quoted or bare?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

Is there a way to distinguish these attributes values without parsing the html in javascript?

```
<a attr="value"></a>
<a attr='value'></a>
<a attr=value></a>
```

I would like to distinguish them to apply specific behavior for a templating system such as

```
<a attr=value></a>
```

would directly set the element property, while

```
<a attr="value"></a>
```

would set the element attribute

Comment: The last one isn't valid XHTML, [attribute values *must* be quoted](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.4). What's the context, why do you *want* to distinguish them?

Comment: It's for special behavior for a templating lib

Comment: Please expand further in an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML sets the attribute values to double quotes `"` when rendered. If you are trying to check an HTML string before being set as `.innerHTML` you can use `RegExp`.

Comment: So there's no way to differentiate them without parsing/searching through the html ?

Comment: @Banou26 What do you mean by "differentiate them"?

Comment: I just find it weird that they are valid to parse but once they're rendered they are set with double quotes.
Just ignore my upper comment, thanks for your answer, i'll just find a way to do what i wanted.